# computed properties in c++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hello i stumbled upon a problem i have code like this:

```
void MainWindow::function()
{
    int x = y.size();

    if(x > 0)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_0->setText("0");
    }
    if(x > 1)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_1->setText("1");
    }
    if(x > 2)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText("2");
    }
}
```

and i want to do it in one for loop like this:

```
void MainWindow::function()
{
    int x = y.size()

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_($i)->setText(i);
    }    
}
```

is that possible or is it only possible in interpreted languages like javascript(computed properties). Am i on the right track by doing this to avoid code redundancy or am i wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot play with variable name, but you can have array, so you might do:

```
void MainWindow::function()
{
    std::array/*<QLineEdit*, 3>*/ line_edits{ui->lineEdit_0, ui->lineEdit_1, ui->lineEdit_2};
    const int x = y.size();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != line_edits.size(); ++i) {
        if (x > i) {
            line_edits[i]->setText(std::to_string(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of `lineEdit`'s, so the code becomes like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    ui->lineEdit[ i ]->setText( i );
}
```

Comment: i created those lineEdits in QtCreator design mode, i don't know how i make them to an array of lineEdits.